# Translations in Django 2.2 is not working

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-2.0

I'm working on a project using Python(3.7) and Django(2.2) in which I have to make the site available in 2 languages (English and Chinese). I have searched a lot and tried every possible solution but no success.
Here's what I have tried:

1. Install `gettext` on my system and link it
2. Add the following setting in `settings.py`:

   Add middleware `'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',` after `Session` and before `Common`, then add `USE_I18N = True` & `USE_L10N = True`, after that mentioned the languages as:

   ```
   LANGUAGES = (
       ('en', _('English')),
       ('zh-hans', _('简体中文')),
   )
   ```

   then add locale path as:

   ```
   LOCALE_PATHS = (
       os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),
   )
   ```
3. Then run the command as: `django-admin makemessages -all` it creates the directory as:

   ```
   └── zh_hans
   └── LC_MESSAGES
       └── django.po
   ```
4. After that, I add the translations in `django.po` and ran the command as `django-admin compilemessage` which generate the file `django.mo`
5. I added a url for `i18n` as:

   ```
   re_path(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18))
   ```
6. and below is my template which is loading by `render` from view as:

   ```
   {% load i18n %}
   <form action="{% url 'set_language' %}" method="post">
         {% csrf_token %}
         <input name="next" type="hidden" value="{{ redirect_to }}"/>
         <select name="language">
                {% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
                {% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
                {% for lang in LANGUAGES %}
                <option value="{{ lang.0 }}" {% if lang.0 == LANGUAGE_CODE %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>
                {{ lang.1 }} ({{ lang.0 }})
                </option>
                {% endfor %}
          </select>
          <input type="submit" value="Go"/>
   </form>
   <h1>{% trans 'Test 2' %}</h1> 
   {% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
   <h3>{{ LANGUAGE_CODE }} </h3>
   <h4>{% translate "Welcome to our page" %}</h4>
   ```

> When I  change the language by selecting from the dropdown, the `LANGUAGE_CODE` it prints correctly, but the text below `Welcome to our page` is not translating.

What I did wrong?

Comment: Did you restart the development server?

Comment: yes, I did and also accessing the site from private window.

Comment: I am not sure but can you pls try renaming the folder `zh_hans` to `zh_Hans`. Reference: zh_hans

Comment: renam zh_zhas to zh_Hans work for me, thank you so much